# String similarity metrics

Tags: python, difflib

This code checks the similarity of sentences

```
normalized1 = s1.lower()
normalized2 = s2.lower()
matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2)
print(matcher.ratio())
```

But he has a minus, if you swap words in places, then the similarity will already be much less. How can this be fixed?

```
s1 = 'Hello wolrd'
s2 = 'Hello wolds'
normalized1 = s1.lower()
normalized2 = s2.lower()
matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2)
print(matcher.ratio()) # 0.91666666

s1 = 'Hello wolrd'
s2 = 'Wolds hello'
normalized1 = s1.lower()
normalized2 = s2.lower()
matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2)
print(matcher.ratio()) # 0.45454545
```

Comment: `SequenceMatcher` computes diffs between *sequences* - i.e. order matters

Comment: Is there another function that will help me?

Comment: if order is not important for you then maybe you should split into list of words, sort this list and join words again into string - and then check similarity

Comment: It's brilliant!